# Order of operations Python

Tags: python

The order of operations in my code seems off...

[image]

```py
numbers=[7, 6, 4]
result = 1
for num in numbers:
        result *= num - 3
        print(result)
```

In this code, I would expect the following to occur...

```
result=1
result = 1 * 7 - 3 = 7 - 3 = 4
result = 4 * 6 - 3 = 24 - 3 = 21
result = 21 * 4 - 3 = 84 - 3 = 81
```

HOWEVER, running the program outputs

result = 1

result = 1 * 7 - 3 = 1 * 4 = 4

result = 4 * 6 - 3 = 4 * 3 = 12

result = 12 * 4 - 3 = 12 * 1 = 12

```
Why with the *= operator is the order of operations altered? 
My understanding is it does not have any special properties it merely saves space instead of writing: 
result = result * num - 3 
we get
result *= num - 3

and for some reason..  (result = result * num - 3) != (result *= num - 3)
```

Comment: `result *= nim - 3` is equivalent to `result = result * (num - 3)`

Comment: If the operations were applied with `-` last, then first you'd do `result *= num`, and then you'd subtract 3 from that but not assign it to anything (because there's no assignment implied by the `-` operator).  That would obviously be nonsensical, which is why it doesn't work like that.  Instead the entire RHS of the `*=` gets evaluated together, as if you'd put parens around it, before the multiplication and assignment happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why with the *= operator is the order of operations altered?

The *= is not an operator, it's delimiter. Check the '2. Lexical analysis' of 'The Python Language Reference':

> The following tokens are operators:
>
> ```
> +       -       *       **      /       //      %      @
> <<      >>      &       |       ^       ~       :=
> <       >       <=      >=      ==      !=
> ```

> The following tokens serve as delimiters in the grammar:
>
> ```
> (       )       [       ]       {       }
> ,       :       .       ;       @       =       ->
> +=      -=      *=      /=      //=     %=      @=
> &=      |=      ^=      >>=     <<=     **=
> ```
>
> The period can also occur in floating-point and imaginary literals. A
> sequence of three periods has a special meaning as an ellipsis
> literal. The second half of the list, the augmented assignment
> operators, serve lexically as delimiters, but also perform an
> operation.

Moreover, in your code you have the, augmented assignment statement, as per '7.2.1. Augmented assignment statements':

> **Augmented assignment is the combination, in a single statement, of a binary operation and an assignment statement**:
>
> [...]
>
> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal
> assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression
> list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment
> on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target.
> The target is only evaluated once.
>
> **An augmented assignment expression like x += 1 can be rewritten as x =
> x + 1 to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect.** In the
> augmented version, x is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the
> actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than
> creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object
> is modified instead.
>
> Unlike normal assignments, augmented assignments evaluate the
> left-hand side before evaluating the right-hand side. For example,
> a[i] += f(x) first looks-up a[i], then it evaluates f(x) and performs
> the addition, and lastly, it writes the result back to a[i].

The '6.16. Evaluation order' says:

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

You can also check the '6.17. Operator precedence' chapter, but it's not about the statements.

Answer (score 0):

The expression on the right hand side of the `*=` is evaluated *first*.

`7 - 3` => `4` which multiplied by `1` is `4`.

`6 - 3` => `3` which multiplied by `4` is `12`.

`4 - 3` => `1` which multiplied by `12` is `12`.

To achieve what you are expecting:

```
numbers = [7, 6, 4]
result = 1
for num in numbers:
    result = result * num - 3
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

the *= means that the * will be used between what's before it and what's after so you need to get result_2 in this example to get what you want :

```
numbers = [7,6,4]
result = 1 
result_2 = 1 
for number in numbers:
    result *= number -3 
    result_2  = result_2 * number -3
    print(result, result_2)
```

Comment: While the parentheses may aid reading the code and understanding order of operations, they are unnecessary in `result_2 = (result_2 * number) -3`

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers=[7, 6, 4] 
result = 1 
for num in numbers: 
    result *= num-3   
print(result)
```

The *= operator is a compound assignment operator, which means that it combines the assignment operator = with another operator
https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-the-compound-assignment-identity-operators-in-python

```
numbers=[7, 6, 4] 
result = 1 
for num in numbers: 
    result = result*num-3
    print(result)
```